# Unsigned Long does not contain valid value

Tags: c++

My question is something I find very weird.
In fact, I'm listing all the child processes of a given process.

For this, I use : [How to find all child processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009552/how-to-find-all-child-processes) and RC's answer.

But, I need an exit with unsigned long.
And the solution give some string based on a `char[]`

If I want to get `unsigned long`, I need to modify the code to get only numeric value. The other case will not be correct.

So I've put the `char` as `unsigned long`. Then, the `scanf` with `%ld` tags.

But I'm getting crap ...

Why does that not work ?

EDIT : Code :

```
const char *name = "top";
char command[100];
unsigned long parentID; unsigned long processID;

strcpy(command, "ps -C "); strcat(command, name); strcat(command, " --format '%P %p'");

FILE *fp = popen(command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) fprintf(stderr, "Error in reading PID child processes information !\n");

while(fscanf(fp, "%lu %lu", parentID, processID) != EOF) {
    printf("PID : %lu Parent : %lu \n", processID, parentID);
}

return processID;
```

With, `%s` and `char[256]`, this work !

EDIT : Toughts

I was thinking of two ways to do this:

- First, using `unsigned long` instead of `char[]`.
- Second, convert `char[]` to `unsigned long` after reading the file. However, I'd need to read it line by line. Is it possible with `popen` ?

Comment: You have an error in your code.

Comment: Obviously your code is wrong. Since you did not show your code you are making it needlessly hard. Word of advice: don't conceal the details.

Comment: Okay, I'm adding it !

Comment: Thx for downvote btw, very encouraging ! ;) It's nice to be a beginner here !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I've put the `char` as `unsigned long`. Then, the `scanf()` with `%ld` tags.

And here your program invokes undefined behavior, since the type specifier for `unsigned long` is `%lu`.

(And probably there are some other, impossible-for-us-to-tell errors as well in your code; changing the return values from `char *` to `unsigned long` is anything but trivial.)

Comment: Is there a way to convert char[] to unsigned long that is simplier than the ones with byte shifting ?
Can I open a File with popen and read it line by line ?

Comment: @MikeTelson Now how those two are related?

Comment: Well, if the first way does not work, I need a B plan ... This is for getting unsigned long from char[], I already have a working solution with output as char[]. I saw ways to convert from char[] to unsigned ... but they are a bit ... hard ...

Comment: @MikeTelson Is that `char[]` actually a NUL-terminated string with the decimal (or whatever kind of) representation of a non-negative integer number? If it is, use `strtoul()`.

Comment: Well, it seems to work ! But I got also a string, that is converted to 0. But I don't think any User process has the PID "0" doesn't it ? If not, a simple if will solve the problem

Comment: @MikeTelson Perhaps either there indeed is one, or the representation of the numbers is not what you assume it to be.

Comment: I'm completely sure my numbers are accurate PIDs. What I'm not sure is what become of the strings I'm parsing with strtoul ... well, I'll go on with that. Thanks for the response anyways.