# is there a way to tell if a process is a child if it did fork and then setsid

Tags: linux, setsid

If a process did `fork` then child did `setsid`, is there any way to tell that it was the child of the first process? Is there any way to kill such process together with its parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setsid` does not destroy the parent/child relation. So you still can get the children of a process, e. g. as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153976/how-do-i-get-the-parent-process-id-of-a-given-child-process) (link us ubuntu specific, but this works for any other distribution).

The parent process always can keep track of its direct children easily, as fork returns their id (grand children gets more [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1012074/1312382)...) and send a signal to any of its children on exiting (gracefully).

`prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, <signal>)` (convenient way to make the children receive a signal, if parent dies), too, will survive a call to setsid.